# Put additional char within sql string query

Tags: vb.net

Probably simple question but dont want to screw it up. Below my query:

```
Dim strCmd As String = ""
strCmd &= " UPDATE tbElemPics"
strCmd &= " SET    PicturePath = Stuff(PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)"
strCmd &= " + 1, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)"
strCmd &= " + 1) - Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath) + 1) - 1, @newvalue)"
strCmd &= " WHERE  Substring(PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)"
strCmd &= " + 1, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)"
strCmd &= " + 1) - Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath) + 1) - 1) = @oldvalue"


Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strCmd, con)
```

And now i have to mark string which i am passing in that place `= @oldvalue"`
with `N` so for instance `= N'mysomeoldvalue'` . Can i just simply do `= N@oldvalue"` ? I have to use it because of specific characters. Hope you know what i mean

Comment: I would highly recommend turning this into a stored procedure instead of having a huge SQL string like this.

Answer (score 0):

It already passes as an NVarchar value, you don't need to do anything special. ie:

```
Dim strCmd As String = <sql>UPDATE tbElemPics
  SET    PicturePath = Stuff(PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1) + 1, 
    Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1) + 1) - 
    Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath) + 1) - 1, @newvalue)
  WHERE  Substring(PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)+ 1, 
    Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath)+1)+ 1) - 
    Charindex('/', PicturePath, Charindex('/', PicturePath) + 1) - 1) = @oldvalue
</sql>
  Using con As New SqlConnection( "server=.\sqlExpress;Database=Test;Trusted_Connection=yes")
  Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strCmd, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newValue", "My Unicode value")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldValue", "My Unicode value 2")
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
  End Using
  End Using
```

Comment: what you saing is my old value is passed as N'   so i dont need to change nothing?

Comment: yes. You can see it yourself using Profiler (or ExpressProfiler if you don't have profiler).